# Application not sending or receiving data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I am creating a simple practice restful application and I'm trying to test my routes.

My routes look like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const posts = Post.find();
    res.json(posts);
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });

    post.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({ message: err});
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Here is where i make the mongodb connection as well as the .env file with the db connection:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require('dotenv/config');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Import Routes
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");

app.use('/posts', postRoute);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("home");
});

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
{   useNewUrlParser: true, //depriciated without this
    useUnifiedTopology: true}, //depriciated without this
() => console.log('connected to db'));

app.listen(3000);

//env file:___________________________________________________________
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb+srv://user-0:<test>@cluster0.wb39f.mongodb.net/<test-db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When I send a get request on postman I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeConnection'
    |     property 'base' -> object with constructor 'Mongoose'
    |     property 'connections' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    --- index 0 closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\routes\posts.js:7:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\westo\Documents\code stuff\restful\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

And when I send a post request I receive a time out with this message:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/posts
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.1
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 59a4d266-3607-4b7b-b952-a843e4e36192
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

As requested here is the Post Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }/*,
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    }*/
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema);
```

I'm not sure what the problem is with my code or my database. Based on all the tutorials I've seen they all do set up and write their code basically the was i do it. I think there may be a problem with how my application is trying to connect to mlab but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you add the file where you have established the connection to `mongodb`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the File, where you are specifying the Scheme for Post if you are using mongoose?

I guess you do

It could be the problem is with seraializing the Promise you get from mongoose.
Try to do it with async-await or .then() like u did in the post method

Answer (score 0):

Database operations are `asynchronous` operations. Hence I would suggest to use `async-await` to your route-controller functions.

For example:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.json(posts);
});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const post = await Post.create({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.description
        });
        res.json(data);
    }
      catch(err) {
        res.json({ message: err});
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

This should atleast solve the issues with pushing/retriving data from the database.
The problem related to connection to MongoDB can be checked once this is in place.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seems to have helped with the socket hangup on post requests. However it is still not finding the sample post in the database or posting new ones despite correctly sending back a response with the post json.

Comment: Updated my answer with correct mongoose queries. I had put the wrong method calls for `find` and `create` funtionalities

Comment: Refer: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find and https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

Comment: after refining the code to meet proper specifications there are still timeout errors, so there must be something extra going on here

Answer (score 0):

When you use a find() you have to pass an object as an argument to find all the posts, And the body parser have to be  `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded{ extended: true })`